# Boundary of a $2$-chain

Tags: differential-geometry

If $c$ is a singular $1$-cube in $\mathbb{R}^2 \backslash \left\{ (0,0)\right\}$ with $c(0)=c(1)$, show that there is an integer $n$ such that: $c-c_{(1,n)} = \partial (c^2)$ for some $2$-chain $c^2$.

Comment: What is "c(subscript:1,n)"?

Comment: The subscript for c is (1,n). I don't know how to use the special characters

Comment: I've been doing some editing to your question: hope I've written what you meant. (You can rollback, if I made any mistake.) But I still don't understand what $c_{(1,n)}$ stands for. As for the tag: I don't see any smooth map there, are you sure that "topology" wouldn't be more correct?

Comment: If you want to learn LaTeX quickly (those "special characters"), click on the words beside "edited" in your question and then on "view source".

Comment: I think what the other commenters mean is that you should try to explain your terminology (like $c_{(1,n)}$) so that others can interpret the question properly.  Perhaps provide a motivation for why you're interested in the problem, or a source for where you found it (say, Spivak's "Calculus on Manifolds" Problem 4-24).

Comment: @Agusti Roig The editing is perfect, I don't think I will be very helpful with the notation... that's partly where I get lost.

Comment: @Jesse Madnick The question is from Spivak's "Calculus on Manifolds" and I actually already have the answer given from the book since we've already turned in this assignment. I was hoping someone would be able to interpret the problem in lower level language than Spivak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so, as Jesse says, this is problem 4-24 from Little Spivak. Maybe you should look at problem 4-23, where he explains what $c_{(1,n)}$ is: a parametrization of the circumference of radius $1$, centered at the origin, that goes round the origin $n$ times

$$
c_{(1,n)} (t) = (\cos 2\pi nt, \sin 2\pi nt) \ .
$$

So the problem says that, given any closed parametrized curve $c(t)$, there is an integer $n$ such that this $c$ together with $c_{(1,n)}$ are the boundary of some $2$-chain $c^2$.

If I'm not wrong, this $n$ is the *winding number* of $c$; that is, the number of times $c$ goes round the origin. So, if $c$ goes round the origin one time, you need the circumference $c_{(1,1)}$ that goes round the origin once too; if $c$ goes round twice, you need $c_{(1,2)}$...

Maybe you should try first problem 4-23, where Spivak asks a similar question, but where $c$ is also a circumference (of different radius). There you see too that you need both circumferences to go round the origin the same number of times in order they are the boundary of some $2$-chain. For instance, if $n=1$ (just once round the origin), these circumferences are the boundary of a regular anulus.

Anyway, you may try to take a look at [Little Spivak solutions](http://www.ms.uky.edu/~ken/ma570/). They are quite right. For instance, in the solution to 4-24, Ken Kubota (the author of these solutions), begins computing $L = \int_0^1 c^*(d\theta)$, which is the winding number of $c$ multiplied by $2\pi$.

Comment: Just a very small comment. The solution in the link above (which, as @Agustí Roig mentioned here, begins by computing $L$), while exhibiting the important idea behind the winding number, suffer a minor lack that Spivak has defined the integral of forms over chains only in the next section after Prob 4-24. For those who are interested in a solution without using such integral, I have attempted to propose one here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4251932/179461. Everyone is welcome to double check if my solution contains any error and improve it together.